# Алгоритм Флойда, почему вложенности циклов именно такие?

Tags: алгоритм

Я неплохо разобрался в алгоритме флойда, но один вопрос ещё остался: почему вложенности циклов именно в таком порядке?

Почему алгоритм работает некорректно, если их поменять местами?

Например, при таком порядке перебора вершин алгоритм не работает:

```
Начальная вершина
Конечная вершина
Промежуточная вершина
```

А вот при таком порядке всё правильно:

```
Промежуточная вершина
Начальная вершина
Конечная вершина
```

В чём же разница? Как это работает? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вся идея алгоритма Флойда заключается в том, что он *одновременно* решает задачу кратчайшего пути для *всех пар вершин в графе*, а не для одной конкретной пары `i, j`.

Если рассматривать [схему реализации из Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0)

```
for k = 1 to n
  for i = 1 to n
    for j = 1 to n
      W[i][j] = min(W[i][j], W[i][k] + W[k][j])
```

то вся идея формирования матрицы `W` в алгоритме Флойда заключается в том, что новые значения матрицы `W` для шага `k` формируются на основе "старых" значений матрицы `W` (c шага `k - 1`). Как вы сами видите, при формировании элемента `W[i][j]` используются "старые" значения из посторонных элементов `W[i][k]` и `W[k][j]`. Они должны быть к этому моменту уже готовы, т.е. полная матрица `W` для значения `k - 1` должна быть уже сформирована.

То есть для того, чтобы выполнять перевычисление `W` на шаге `k` нам надо иметь полностью сформированную `W` с шага `k - 1`. Вот поэтому цикл по `k` и сделан самым внешним.

Если вы просто ни о чем не задумываясь поменяете местами циклы

```
for i = 1 to n
  for j = 1 to n
    for k = 1 to n
      W[i][j] = min(W[i][j], W[i][k] + W[k][j])
```

то при выполнении внутреннего цикла по `k` будет происходить обращение к `W[i][k]` и `W[k][j]`, которые не имеют никакого отношения к шагу `k - 1` (они будут содержать либо начальные значения, либо финальные значения этого элемента) . Алгоритм не будет работать правильно.

Если вам захочется вдруг внешние циклы сделать по `i` и `j`, то фактически вы будете применять алгоритм Флойда к каждой паре `i, j` в отдельности. Получится что-то вроде

```
for i = 1 to n
  for j = 1 to n
  {
    /* Применяем алгоритм Флойда для пары `i, j` */

    /* Переинициализируем матрицу `W` */

    for k = 1 to n
      /* Формируем матрицу `W` шага `k` для пары `i` И `j` */
      for ii = 1 to n
        for jj = 1 to n
          W[ii][jj]= ...
  }
```

Теперь вам придется формировать *полную* матрицу шага `k` для пары `i` И `j` - а это снова циклы по `ii` и `jj`. Такая реализация будет весьма неразумной.

Так как матрица `W` шага `k` является актуальной для *всех* пар `i, j` одновременно, разумно обрабатывать шаг `k` именно так: для всех пар `i, j` одновременно.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь, когда я взял информацию и у вас, и у преподавателя, я наконец понял что к чему. Это же элементарно, странно вообще, что понял не сразу :D